# get data of IBM Workload Scheduler Dashboard from shell script

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, workload-scheduler

I need to extract some data from IBM Workload Scheduler Dashboard and need to do some further operation on it.
I just thought to do it in below steps:

```
curl "Dashboard URL"  > report.txt
operation-1 on report.txt
opreation-2 on report.txt
mail the output report.txt
```

I was not able to find any API or script to do like this where to get data of Workload Scheduler dashboard data on unix box.

any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Tivoli is a software brand from IBM with tens, maybe hundred, of different products in it. You probably have to specify which product dashboard are you referring to and which data you want to extract.

Comment: @FrancoMossotto its "IBM Workload Scheduler"

Answer (score 0):

The IBM Workload Scheduler dashboard gets data from IWS engines (IWSd or IWSz) via APIs.

The dashboard includes javascript code running in the browser and makes several different calls to the DWC server, so it's not possible to get the data query the dashboard URL.

Instead of querying the dashboard URL, I recommend to consider calling engine APIs from your script.

On IWSd, since 9.3 FP2, there are REST APIs that can be called in script with curl or you can call them from more advanced scripting languages like perl, php, python, javascript that can easily work with REST APIs. They will be available soon also for IWSz.

You can find REST APIs documentation [here](https://start.wa.ibmserviceengage.com/twsd/) or directly on your master at `https://<masterhost>:<httpsport>/twsd/`

On previous IWSd version, or on IWSz you can use the Java EE APIs, that will require to write a Java client. The documentation is available [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGSPN_9.4.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.4/common/src_dgd/awsddjapi.htm)